# How to align headers underneath images using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a clothing website just as a project to learn and I barely know anything about flexbox and decided to use it for this and I'm trying to get the product name and price to go under the image rather then to the right as shown in the image here:
[What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fLKf.jpg)

```css
.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: indianred;
}
  
.product-card {
    padding: 2%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 16%;
    display: flex; /* so child elements can use flexbox stuff too! */
    flex: 1 16%;
}

.product-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.product-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.product-info a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.product-info a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="products">

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="images/dino.png">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <a href="dino.html">
        <h4>Dino T-Shirt</h4>
        <h5>$14.99</h5>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-image">
          <img src="images/hawaiian-1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
        <a href="hawaiian.html">
          <h4>Hawaiian T-Shirt</h4>
          <h5>$14.99</h5>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-image">
          <img src="images/blue-long-sleeve.png">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
        <a href="blue-long.html">
          <h4>Blue Long Sleeve</h4>
          <h5>$14.99</h5>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-image">
          <img src="images/blue-long.png">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
        <a href="#">
          <h4>blue Long Sleeve Button Up</h4>
          <h5>$14.99</h5>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="product-card">
        <div class="product-image">
          <img src="images/gray-long-sleeve-collar.png">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
        <a href="gray-long-collar.html">
          <h4>Collar Gray Long Sleev</h4>
          <h5>$14.99</h5>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

If anyone could help me out I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm sorry I completed forgot to add the code

Comment: Use `flex-direction:column` on your cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case flex isn't really required, and you might want to consider using the [figure](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp) tag for your use case.

PS - In the future, generally a display of effort with a reproducible example is required but welcome to SO with a freebie ;)

UPDATE: Since you updated your question with example. Just add `flex-direction: column;` to the `.product-card` class since `flex` is direction `row` by default. Cheers.

```html
<figure>
  <img height="200" width="400" src="https://picsum.photos/400/200">
  <figcaption>
    I'm info about this image, hi
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```